# How to make the validation indicator disappear when condition is false

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a method to validate Textbox

```
private void TextBox_Validation(object sender, CancelEventArgs e, TextBox txt, int requiredLength, string errorMessage)
{
    ErrorProvider er = new ErrorProvider();

    if (txt.Text.Length < requiredLength)
    {
        er.SetError(txt, errorMessage);
       e.Cancel = true;
    }
    else
    {
       er.SetError(txt, null);
       e.Cancel = false;
     }
 }
```

I run it from textbox validating event

```
private void txtIssueDescription_Validating(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
{
    TextBox_Validation(sender, e, txtIssueDescription, 20, "Desription must have at least 20 letters");
}
```

The issue: even the length of the message is greater than 20, the red indicator still indicates the message as shown in the image. When the condition is true, it does what it is supposed to do.

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ek2so.jpg)

Comment: You should not create a new instance of `ErrorProvider` each time. Just use the existing instance. To do so, drop an instance of `ErrorProvider` on form and then you can use it by its name `errorProvider1.SetError(textBox1, "Some Error");`

Comment: :) thanks, I put the declare outside of the method in the partial class Form1 and it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating new error provider each time:

```
ErrorProvider er = new ErrorProvider();
```

Changes to it will not do anything with `ErrorProvider` component present on the form.